# subprocess using different path in canopy?

Tags: python, path, environment-variables, subprocess, canopy

I have an executable in `~/.bin/`, which is in my PATH variable in my shell and in my OS X path (it appears in `launchctl getenv PATH`). When I execute

```
subprocess.call(['myexecutable'])
```

from ipython, then it works, but when I execute the same call in the canopy editor, then I get

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

also using the keyword `shell=True` doesn't help. Does anyone know how to get my command to run in the Canopy editor?

**EDIT:**
Setting the `PYTHONPATH` variable system wide with `launchctl setenv PYTHONPATH $PYTHONPATH:~/.bin` seems to work, but the same approach fails when I try it for the `PATH` variable. In the canopy console `os.environ.copy()` then shows the correct `PYTHONPATH` with `~/.bin` in the end, but `PATH` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the full path to `myexecutable`:

```
subprocess.call([os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".bin", 'myexecutable'))])
```

Or you can explicitly add the ~/.bin directory to the `PATH` being used in `subprocess.call`:

```
my_env = os.environ.copy()
my_env['PATH'] = "%s:%s" % (my_env['PATH'], os.expanduser("~/.bin"))
subprocess.call([myexecuteable], env=my_env)
```

If you'd rather just change Canopy's PATH directly, [their website](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23665767-How-do-I-set-PYTHONPATH-and-other-environment-variables-for-Canopy-) suggests adding the following to `/etc/launchd.conf`:

```
setenv PATH $PATH:/homedir/.bin
```

(I don't have OSX and can't test this, though).

Comment: I think modifying `/etc/launchd.conf` is the same as I do (`launchctl setenv ...`), so that doesn't seem to help. I also don't want to use the full path in the code, the code should be able to run wherever that tool is in the `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting environment variables in OSX is quite idiosyncratic. See this article for links: https://support.enthought.com/entries/23665767-How-do-I-set-PYTHONPATH-and-other-environment-variables-for-Canopy-